# jdbcTemplate.query(query, ROW_MAPPER) создает пустые объекты

Tags: java

Объект:

```
public class MissedCall {

    private Timestamp dateTime;
    private String callerId;    
    private Long duration;       

    public MissedCall(Timestamp dateTime, String callerId, long duration) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime
        this.callerId = callerId;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

Метод, выполняющий запрос:

```
public class JdbcMissedCallRepositoryImpl implements JdbcMissedCallRepository {
    ...

    private static final RowMapper<MissedCall> ROW_MAPPER = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MissedCall.class);
    ...
    public List<MissedCall> getForLastDays() {
    ...
    List<MissedCall> missedCalls = jdbcTemplate.query(query, ROW_MAPPER);
    ...
    }
```

В результате, в List'е я получаю пустой объект MissedCall...

Если запрос выполнить ручками, то результат такой:

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+
| atm                 | asrc        | adur |
+---------------------+-------------+------+
| 2018-05-02 19:46:21 | 89181112233 |    4 |
+---------------------+-------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Что ему нужно, чтоб он сопоставил поля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Кому интересно - название полей объекта должны совпадать с названиями столбцов в выводе запроса.
т.е. результат должен быть:

```
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| dateTime            | callerId    | duration |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| 2018-05-02 19:46:21 | 89181112233 |        4 |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: это если вы используете `BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MissedCall.class)`. А можно создать `RowMapper` через `new` и растыкать поля сеттерами/через конструктор как нужно